# FactoryGirl with Rspec to create a dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I am working on Ruby on Rails rspec testing and I have a question. Apparently, I have to create a dictionary, sort like

```
@example = {:attr1 => "somevalue", :attr2 => "some", 
            :attr3 => "someother", :stt => "abc"}
```

It is a very long dictionary so I would like to make it inside a factory. That would make the test look nicer.

I have been looking around but I only see FactoryGirl is designed for ActiveRecord object. Does anyone know how to use FactoryGirl to make a dictionary like this ?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: why FactoryGirl and not a simple helper that returns that hash?

Comment: I think that using factorygirl will help me run the test with minimal change to other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, in fact, use FactoryGirl for this:

See [Custom Construction](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction). Basically, you provide `initialize_with` to the factory definition and use your initializer function to set the dictionary values to what you need. You still get the full power of sequences, traits, etc, but can get back ***any*** Ruby object... not just an ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

So, straight from the [Getting Started page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

> The name is used to guess the class of the object by default, but it's possible to explicitly specify it...If you're creating ActiveRecord objects, that means...

This suggests that you can specify any class as the class the factory is creating, which should include dictionaries.